# Diamond shaped question mark while viewing title in HTML

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have following code in html:

```
<head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title> Flora – Create a Plate – Make Your Own Kid’s Plate</title>

        <meta name="Description" content="Create your own unique personalised kid’s plate with backgrounds, stickers, stamps & your own drawings!" />

        <meta property="og:title" content="Flora – Create a Plate – Make Your Own Kid’s Plate"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://somewebaddress"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://somewebaddresswithimage"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Flora - Create a plate"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Create your own unique personalised kid’s plate with backgrounds, stickers, stamps & your own drawings!"/>


        <meta property="og:keywords" content="create a plate, custom kid’s plate, make your own plate, flora"/>
```

I am facing problem that, when title is viewd, It involves some special characters like '(single quote), -(dash) .

For these characters its showing me diamond shaped question mark.

I have used UTF-8 in my meta tag for avoiding this.

```
 <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

But its not viewing me correctly.

What can be the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Looks like it's actually an Apostrophe from the single-byte encoding of ISO-8859-1 but you're casting it to a multi-byte like `UTF-8` which causes the "replacement character". Please change your charset to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I changed it as <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">  but same problem

Comment: Latin1 (or ISO-8859-1) does not have any curly apostrophe. Instead, it may be a proprietary encoding, like windows-1252. But rather than changing the declared charset, you should rather reencode it to UTF-8. Any good text editor can save a document as UTF-8.

Comment: This example actually works. Is it a static file or content served by a server? Maybe header set by a server may be a problem. Check for "content-type" header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape typographic characters. Instead of apostrophe use this HTML entity `&#8217;`. Others can be found here http://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography.

**UPDATE**

For local files: save it with editor that supports UTF8 (with BOM preferably). Open it in Chrome and check tools-encoding menu. It tells you what actual encoding is browser using.

If you are using some kind of server. In Chrome press F12 for developer tools then go to network tab, reload page. On right side of the panel look for Response header Content-Type.

Comment: So 2000 and late... in normal context (outside elements and attributes), only two characters require to be escaped: < and &, and that's it! (in practice it's a good idea to escape > too)
All other entities are provided for convenience and/or for extending old (non Unicode-based) encoding with all of Unicode characters. That's said yes it may work for Angel's particular problem, but what about the next character you did not thought of?

Comment: Indeed. I was just trying to avoid potential server side encoding problem. But it should be added to the answer.

Comment: @JanPfeifer your link was helpful. I have added answer above. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

The “diamond shaped question mark” is “�” U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER and it indicates character-level data error: the browser has encountered bytes that do not represent a character at all in the character encoding being applied. It may also be an actual U+FFFD character in the document itself, in which case it means that some software used to generate the document encountered such malformed bytes and replaced them by U+FFFD.

The ultimate cause of the problem cannot be decided without additional information, such as the raw byte data involved, HTTP headers sent by a browser, and possibly the software used to generate the HTML file. For example, it is quite possible that the HTML file is actually windows-1252 encoded; windows-1252 data generally causes errors like this when interpreted as UTF-8. Changing just a `meta` tag would not help here if the server declares window-1252 (or iso-8859-1, which is actually taken as windows-1252) in an HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

I was pulling out some old legacy content to be repurposed so my case was less critical but what I ended up doing to get rid of the diamond shaped question marks was to run a replacement function on the content pulled from the database where the regular expression pattern was copied from the source it originally came from using a text editor. I located a diamond question mark in the source content by copying the text right before it and then found the offending character using search of that text phrase. In a normal text editor this character will look like a space but I was able to determine that it was not a space because my text editor is advanced and has a "view non-printing text feature" where spaces show up as a center dot but this particular character did not have a dot indicating it was most certainly not a space.  So, I copied the character from the source and put it in the regular expression pattern and proceeded to replace it with a space character. This worked for me.

$patterns = array("/.img/", "/ /"); // the 2nd pattern is copied via cut paste from the source

$replacements = array(".jpg", " "); // the 2nd replacement here is a space

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);

Answer (score 0):

By writting like below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title> Flora &#8211; Create a Plate &#8211; Make Your Own Kid&lsquo;s Plate</title>
```

`&#8211;` for -

`&lsquo;` for '

Solved my problem.

I taken thopse from the link given by Jan Pfeifer

http://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography